# Calculate Number of Days for multiple dates in the same calendar year

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula that calculates the number days within the same calendar year for multiple dates. Example:

```
  ! POSITION 1 START DATE ! POSITION 2 START DATE ! Days@POS 1 ! Days@POS2 ! 
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  !     1/1/2014          !      9/8/2014         !   250      !     115   !
```

Also, if there is no date in `Position 2 Start Date` then `Days@POS 1` should read as 365 days instead of 250.

I have tried a combination of IF and OR functions together and can't seem to make any progress.

Comment: Share the forumlas you tried and we might be able to help you improve them! :)

Comment: I am using the Below function in Days@POS 1 column:

IF(AD2<>"0",AI2-AD2,$BO$1-AD2) where

AD2 = Position Start Date 1 
AI2 = Position Start Date 2
BO1= 12/31/2014

I want the function to say if AI2 field is blank, then it should be 365 days based on BO1-AD2 otherwise 250 days based on (AI2-AD2)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To restate the requirement, you want to know how many days there are from the given date to the end of the year for 2 dates.  I would take advantage of the fact that Excel stores dates as numbers, so you can simply subtract to find the difference in days.

For this example, I used this for the formula in C2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2-A2,DATE(YEAR(A2)+1,1,1)-A2)
```

This uses the difference between the dates if the second value is a date, or the difference between the first and the end of the year if not.

And this for D2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),DATE(YEAR(B2)+1,1,1)-B2,"")
```

This is just the difference between the second day and end of year if the date is provided, empty string if not

Copying the formulas down as necessary and adding some dates gives me:

```
      A      B       C       D
1   Date 1  Date 2  Days 1  Days 2
2   1/1/14  9/8/14  250     115
3   1/1/14          365 
4   5/15/15 8/1/15  78      153
```

Which seems to meet the requirement.